Dagger 2.52 to use jakarta for the generated code
I have the following dagger 2.52 dependency in my project:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
    <version>2.52</version>
</dependency>

And I have this annotation processor:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>17</release>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <!-- Dagger 2 -->
            <path>
                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>2.52</version>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

Now, when I use IntelliJ to let dagger generate the code, I see something like this:
import dagger.internal.DaggerGenerated;
import dagger.internal.Factory;
import dagger.internal.Preconditions;
import dagger.internal.QualifierMetadata;
import dagger.internal.ScopeMetadata;
import javax.annotation.processing.Generated;
import javax.inject.Provider;

@ScopeMetadata("jakarta.inject.Singleton")
@QualifierMetadata
@DaggerGenerated
@Generated(
    value = "dagger.internal.codegen.ComponentProcessor",
    comments = "https://dagger.dev"
)

I wonder why the imports refers to javax, when I specifically incremented the dagger and dagger-compiler versions.
How can I instruct Dagger to generate code that imports jakarta.inject.Provider instead of javax.inject.Provider ?

Specifically, Dagger 2.52 comes with both javax-inject and jakarta.inject-api dependencies.

To fix your issue, just exclude javax-inject dependency from dagger dependency in the pom.xml:
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
    <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
    <version>2.52</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

Edit:
Update plugin in the pom.xml:
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.13.0</version>
    <configuration>
        <release>17</release>
        <annotationProcessorPaths>
            <!-- Dagger 2 -->
            <path>
                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>dagger-compiler</artifactId>
                <version>2.52</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </path>
            <path>
                <groupId>com.google.dagger</groupId>
                <artifactId>dagger</artifactId>
                <version>2.52</version>
                <exclusions>
                    <exclusion>
                        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
                        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
                    </exclusion>
                </exclusions>
            </path>
        </annotationProcessorPaths>
    </configuration>
</plugin>


Hello Anish! thanks for answering! Unfortunately the generated code still has imports from javax despite the exclusion

@carlospalma I found another thing. Updating my answer.
